# mkdir Permission Denied php script

Tags: php

I want to make and remove directories, and files with a php script

example:

```
<?php
if (!is_dir('examples')) {
    mkdir('examples');
}
?>
```

But I get permission denied.  How can I allow this  one script to run these commands?
I have tried chmod 777 mkdir.php and chmod +s mkdir.php 
which got rid of the Permission denied meaage, but It still doesn't create the folder.

how can i get mkdir() and or rmdir() php function to work?

Please note, I am not using php as a shell script.

Comment: its not the permission of the script you have to worry about its the permission of the folder in which you want to create  new one.

Comment: You probably need to chmod the parent directory that the new folder is going to be. So if you had `/var/www/test/foo` and you wanted to make `/var/www/test/foo/bar` you need to chmod `/var/www/test/foo`

Comment: To what should I chmod it?

Comment: 777, if the user www-data isn't the owner of the parent directory or not in the same group as the owner. Usually it would be 775, tho.

Comment: I got it. Thanks guys. Should I delete this post?

Comment: what ever gives write permission to your script

Comment: be careful with chmod -R 777, that would apply execute permission on all the files which could be dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just chown to the user.
(I just came to put an answer here to mark 'answer found')
Original text:

```
777, if the user www-data isn't the owner of the parent directory or not in the same group as the owner. Usually it would be 775, tho.
```

Credit to Charlotte Dunois